# how to redirect users from old urls to new urls in SEO friendly manner

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Don't think it is a duplicate question asked before.Yeah It is kind of a duplicate but need to clarify something regarding my website.

I have changed my old URLs to new URLs with some more parameters. Like,

old URL1:- http://www.example.com/Threads/24/sample-thread.html

new URL1:- http://threads.example.com/IN/24/215/sample-thread.html // `(IN,215 can be changed. 24 remains)`

old URL1:- http://www.example.com/Threads/25/sample-thread2.html

new URL2:- http://threads.example.com/UK/25/302/sample-thread2.html // `(UK,302 can be changed. 25 remains)`

`Both pages are having same contents and both URLs refers to the same page`. Since there are lot of indexed pages in Google, I don't want to loose my visitors.

So I would like redirect old URL to new URL **without affecting** search engines.What would be the best solution for my case?

`.htaccess` or `php`? what should I go with?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with php

just add following code in your old URL, it will redirect you to new URL

**new URL1**

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://threads.example.com/IN/24/215/sample-thread.html");
?>
```

Do this for all pages

Comment: Thanks Friend. If I redirect it like this will it work as a 301 redirect?

Comment: yah, this is the good way to redirect URL to new page, its SEO friendly redirection method.

Comment: Okay.Since both links go to the same page,I think it will cause infinite redirect? Am I right?

Comment: both links?? you just need to add this code in old page at the top of the page

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that.I decided to remove all old pages from the site.And I think if I use this method,then I cannot delete old pages until new URL getting indexed.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite with `R=301` (permanent redirect) is standard way of dealing with this scenario (moving old URL a newer one).

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Threads/(24)/([^.]+\.html)$ http://threads.example.com/IN/$1/215/$2 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Threads/(25)/([^.]+\.html)$ http://threads.example.com/UK/$1/302/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks friend.What happen if URLs are dynamic and IN,215 are taken from database?

Comment: .htaccess cannot query the database but if there are only bunch of these values you can store them in flat file and utilize RewriteMap feature.